# Stylesheet from wp_enqueue_style is overwritten by plugin

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am using Font Awesome on my theme.

```
wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

I am using another plugin that uses Font Awesome, but its using an old version.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), MSI_VERSION, 'all' );
```

The two methods are using the same handle so only one gets rendered in the HTML... and that is the plugin's old version. I could change my handle but then two Font Awesomes would be loading. I could hack the plugin, but, EWWW!

How do I get my version of Font Awesome to take priority and load?

Comment: what priorities are both of those enqueues hooked on?

Comment: Those are the exact lines of code being called. I checked the [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) docs and I didnt see anything about priorities. How do I see its priority?

Comment: Oooh! You mean the hook's priority! Ah ha. Yeah, I reduced my hook's priority and that got it working! Make that an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` correctly.

**Register** your stylesheet on `wp_loaded`, **enqueue** it on `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
    wp_register_style(
        'fontawesome',
        '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
    );
});
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' );
});
```

When someone tries to call `wp_enqueue_style()` with an URL, WordPress will try to register it automatically, doing the work of `wp_register_style()` behind the curtains. But that will **fail** if the `$handle` is already registered.

Always register scripts and stylesheet on `wp_loaded`. Never use `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` with the second parameter.

Do not fiddle with priorities here. The conflicting plugin might change its own priority, and you start running behind again.

Comment: Did you mean `wp_enqueue_styles` as opposed to `wp_enqueue_scripts` as the action? The former worked for me but the latter didn't. Regardless, thanks for the more informative answer than my question demanded!

Comment: @Jeff There is no action `wp_enqueue_styles`.

Comment: Weird that it is "working" then. Something else must be going on...